# ExactTarget support of Bootstrap CSS v3.3.5

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, landing-page

Can you please let me know if ExactTarget Support Bootstrap CSS v3.3.5.

I am trying to use it on a landing page and it doesn’t seem to work. I have an HTML that works fine, but when I copy the HTML on a microsite it doesn’t work.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  You'll need to provide some more details about what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add CSS files into the Portfolio for use on a microsite.  If it works locally then doesn't work when added to a microsite, then I suspect that a reference to a required file didn't get updated when the HTML was moved.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does support the stated Bootstrap version. There was a different issue with HTML due to which the script wasn't working.